# check if the numbers already given in a array

Tags: arrays, c, random

This is a program from a book that I'm studying. I don't get how this program keeps track of the numbers that have already been taken. The book is terse and I don't understand their explanation. Could someone please help me to understand the details of this code better? Specifically the part indicated in the code comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int maxrange = 49;
const int maxballs = 6;

int rnd(int range);
void seedrnd(void);

int main()
{
    int numbers[maxrange];
    int i, b;

    printf("L O T T O  Z I E H U N G E N\n");
    seedrnd();

    for (i = 0; i < maxrange; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("Drueken sie eingabe fuer die Zahlen dieser Woche: ");
    getchar();

    printf("Es geht los\n");

    //This is the part I am stuck at: where the numbers in the array
    //are checked to see if the number has been used

    for (i = 0; i < maxballs; i++);
    {
        do
        {
            b = rnd(maxrange);
        } while (numbers[b - 1]);
        numbers[b - 1] = 1;
        printf("%i ", b);
    }

    printf("\n\nViel Glueck\n");
    return 0;
}

int rnd(int range)
{
    int r;
    r = rand() % range + 1;
    return (r);
}

void seedrnd(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}
```

Comment: Tip: `while(numbers[b - 1]);` is the same as `while(numbers[b - 1] != 0);`

Comment: I'd do it differently: With every number chosen I'd reduce `maxrange` (more precisely: a duplicate of!) by one. Then you iterate over the array and with every number smaller than or equal to the new one you increment the latter one. The numbers chosen so far need to be sorted for, though – which you achieve by sorting in the new one as soon as an already chosen one is larger. This way you calculate exactly as many random numbers as you have balls to select.

Comment: By the way: Modulo calculations on the result of `rand` provide rather poor distribution – maybe fine for just playing around, for more serious applications you should prefer `rand() * (range + 1) / RAND_MAX` – depending on sizes of `range` and `RAND_MAX` you might need to consider overflow, though.

Comment: The author should have used a better name for `numbers` - e.g. `indexTaken`.

Comment: Opinions and styles vary. I'm a little surprised that no one has yet used the term "flag". That's what `numbers` is - an array of flags, indicating which numbers have been chosen.

Comment: You have a typo `for (i = 0; i < maxballs; i++);` remove `;` at the end, otherwise the loop is not doing anything, except increment `i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the loop is to make sure that you get `maxballs` unique numbers. This is done by using the array `numbers` to "remember" which numbers have been used already.

The idea is as follows.

First the array `numbers` are filled with zeros.

Then a random number is selected. For instance 2. The `while (numbers[b - 1]);` stops because `numbers[1]` is zero.

Then `numbers[1]` is set to 1 here `numbers[b - 1] = 1;`

Then the next random number is selected. If that again should be 2, it will be rejected because now `numbers[1]` is not zero so `while (numbers[b - 1]);` will cause another random number to be selected.

In this way you will get `maxballs` unique numbers.

As commented by @ikegami it's worth to mention that a better way to generating a random sequence of unique number is Fisher-Yates shuffle. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Note that this is a bad approach. It would be better to use a partial [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It wouldn't take any extra memory, and it doesn't have the problem of constantly getting the same numbers.

Comment: @ikegami Full agree that Fisher-Yates is a better approach for get unique random numbers. For this specific case the "trial-and-error" approach is probably not a major issue as OP only need 6 unique numbers out of 49 possible numbers. But still, I should have mentioned Fisher-Yates.